# package com.facebook does not exist

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm using phonegap/cordova and I installed the official facebook plugin in my terminal using `sudo phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="12345678910" --variable APP_NAME="MyAPP"`

It installed just fine in terminal, but now when I open up my app in Android Studio I'm receiving a bunch of com.facebook errors. It seems like the libary is not imported.

Has anyone suffered this issue before? Can anyone help troubleshoot? Thank you. Please see what I am suffering below:

[image]

Comment: not sure why i'm getting downvoted.. it seems like a problem that hasn't been solved in 2 years after numerous google results.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.gradle file to make sure you include the facebook libs in your project dependencies.

If you already have your lib file included in gradle but still have this problem, you need to download the lib file and add it as a external lib manually.

Comment: in my dependencies it automatically added them. do you have documentation on how to add an external lib to the build.gradle?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('Your_Path/xxx/Your_Lib_File_Name.jar')
}                                                                                                                            you should have something like this in your gradle file. If not, that is mean your external lib are not included in your gradle.

Comment: for facebook android sdk, you should have some thing like this:     dependencies { 
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}